# How to protect user to clear checkbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How to protect user to clear checkbox using javascript ?

I want to protect clear checkbox from user using javascript

(not use disabled tag) How can i do that ?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" checked> Do not uncheck
```

Comment: as long as you know if it was checked (or) not, set that value again in the clickhandler

Comment: why display a checkbox at all, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want a checkbox that can't be unchecked but you can simply do this:

```
$(".dontUncheck").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
});

<input type='checkbox' checked  class="dontUncheck" />
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0x9vp6ca/

Comment: How to add `id="c1"` into javascript tag

Comment: you can just change the click handler to this: $("#c1).click(...
and it will listen to the checkbox with id c1

Comment: When checkbox `id="c1"` not check , i don't checked checkbox ?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question

Comment: when checkbox `id="c1"` checked , user not clear 

#######but when checkbox `id="c1"` clear , user can checked

Comment: if you want the user to be able to click on the (unchecked) checkbox first, and then be unable to uncheck it again you can remove the line e.preventDefault(); and you'll accomplish what you need.